# How to use ETL in WSO2?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

We are working on WSO2 ESB for storing some values into database by using proxy.
Now we have requirement to move the data from one DB to reporting DB using ETL. Is there any plugins available to use ETL ? If so, How to use that plugin ?
Please note both the DB are in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use WSO2 DAS [1] which is a product for analyzing and presenting both batch and real time data. By default DAS stores data in H2 database, you can configure this to Postgre DB[2].

Finally you can integrate WSO2 ESB with DAS by using BAM mediator and publish events [3].

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS301/WSO2+Data+Analytics+Server+Documentation

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS301/Setting+up+PostgreSQL

[3] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Integrating+with+WSO2+BAM%2C+WSO2+DAS+and+WSO2+CEP